# How to remove Gnome 3 from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, gnome, uninstall

I'm new to Gnome, and I don't really like it. So that's exactly why I installed Unity 7. So far so good, Unity works like a charm, much better than Gnome, at least this is my opinion. However, now I have 2 settings app,  2 calculators, 2 networks managers, 2 of everything. Is there any way to remove gnome 3 without messing up at all Unity? I don't really like to search an app and instead of showing up only 1 it shows at least 3 different apps with the same icon. Is there any way? Thank you!

Comment: And this shouldn't mess Unity up?

Comment: I don't think so. If happens, you can reinstall that again

Comment: Oh okay... Thanks for the quick reply. It's removing right now!

Comment: okay it finished. It did remove some stuff, but most of the apps are still there.

Comment: Reboot the system. They might disappear. If they don't, try to uninstall manually.

Comment: I did as you said. The first command, it removed some stuff, then I removed the apps manually using the software center. Now it's all good. There is some stuff that I can't understand if I can or can't remove, but mostly is clean now. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: The "Duplicate" apps might have been both SNAP versions that come with a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install, and their counterparts in the regular Ubuntu software repository that will be dependencies of the Unity desktop metapackage.